# Checking Available Room Using MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Everybody. I have a problem with my assignment about hotel booking online, that my problem is difficult to check available room. So I have many table like:

```
tbRoom(RoomID,RoomName,...)
tbReservation(ResID,ResDate,....)
tbReservationDetail(ResID,RoomID,ArrvialDate,DepartureDate,....)
```

I want to get Room that available in between two date.

so, How I do?or DO I need to create more table?

Please help me, Thank for helping....

Answer (score 1):

You can select your reserved rooms and invert:

```
SELECT * FROM tbRoom WHERE RoomID NOT IN (SELECT RoomID FROM tbReservationDetail WHERE ArrvialDate < yourDate AND DepartureDate > yourDate)
```

Comment: Excuse me, Your query is not working it always call all RoomID even, I put date date that between ArrivalDate and DepartureDate....Please Help, I'm waiting your help....

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your result using above 3 tables you specified. but only thing you have to change is that you have to use `RoomID` filed in `tbReservation` table also.

`rbRoom` -> store the distinct rooms
`tbReservation` -> when a room is reserved this table will hold the RoomID and Reservation ID
`tbReservationDetail`  ->stores the other details regarding arrivalDate,DepartureDate etc.

then follow the below query

```
   SELECT * FROM tbRoom WHERE RoomID NOT IN (SELECT RoomID FROM tbReservation     
   tr,tbReservationDetail td WHERE td.ArrvialDate < yourDate AND 
    td.DepartureDate > yourDate  and tr.RoomID=td.RoomID)
```